# Proving if $p|ab$ then $p|a\vee p|b$, then $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

> Let $1\neq p\in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb N$ if $p|ab$ then $p|a\vee p|b$. Prove that $p$ is prime.

My attempt, proof by contradiction:

Suppose $p$ isn't prime, then $\exists t\in \mathbb N:1<t<p:t|p$ and from divisor's definition: $\exists k\in \mathbb N: tk=p$. Placing that in the given will yield:

$kt|ab\to kt|a \vee kt|b$

Now I'm not sure about the next part:

Suppose $k=6, t=3, a=2, b=9$ so $6\cdot 3|9\cdot 2$ but $6\cdot 3 \not \mid2 $ and $6\cdot 3 \not \mid 9$.

Is that the contradiction I was supposed to find?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm following, your question is of the form $(p\to q)\to r$ correct?

Comment: @induktio yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $p$ is not prime, that is, there exist $a>1,b>1$ such that $p = ab$. Then by hypothesis as $p | ab$ we $p| a$ or $p|b$. Switching $a$ and $b$ we can assume that $p|a$, so that $a = pa'$ for some $a'$. But then $p = (pa')b$ so that $1 = a'b$, which contradicts the fact that $b>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that if $p=kt$, $p$ divides $kt$ trivially, but $p$ doesn't divide $k$ nor $t$ since $k, t <p$. It's only a proof by contraposition.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to proceed directly: suppose $p$ verifies the property, and assume that $p=ab, 1\leq a,b\leq p$. We want to show that $a=1$ or $b=1$. But $p\mid ab$ (the quotient is $1$ !). So for example $p\mid a$. I let you find the missing step...